# Cannot import models into view.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have following models.py and views.py . I am trying to change the date to workweek  in views file. But when i try to import date , I get the following error:

NameError at /
name 'date' is not defined

Any idea why ?? and how to fix it ??

---------models.py--------------->>

```
    class metric(models.Model):
      metric = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      date = models.DateField()
      value = models.FloatField()
      goal = models.FloatField()
      Mowner = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

---------views.py ---------------->>

```
from dashboard.models import *
    from .models import metric
    import pandas as pd
    from plotly.offline import plot
    import plotly.express as px
    from datetime import datetime

def index(request):
# Convert date to workweek
    weeks = []
    for date_str in date:
        date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d-%m-%Y')
    week_num = date_obj.isocalendar()[1]
    weeks.append(week_num)
```

I tried importing the metrics in views.py file in different ways but still doesnot  seem to work .

Comment: `date` in `for date_str in date:` is not defined. What do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please fix indentation on packages/modules import
2. You have to query the metrics model to get the date values list. You can try something like this, `date=metric.objects.values_list('date', flat=True)` inside the index function, before `for` loop